# How to send arguments using curl?

Tags: java, curl, arguments

I am trying to add arguments while executing java spring project.

Case) Java standalone : `java -cp target/A.jar myProgram arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4` -> **WORKS!**

How about SPRING-RESTful API case?

Without having arguments, I used
`curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-AUTH-TOKEN: XXXX" -X POST -d "[1234,4567,89012]" http://my.ip.address:port/myProgram`

Then, how can I include arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 in that curl command?

---

*GreetingController.java*

```
package Rest;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import myProgram;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;


//
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

//    @Autowired
//    bboxevolutionTripleFromDB processor;


    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/myProgram", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> doDemo(@RequestHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN") String authToken) {

        try {
            TypeInferenceMain.doDemo(null);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("[");

            sb.append("]");
            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            responseHeaders.setContentType(mediaType);
            return  new ResponseEntity(sb.toString(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        responseHeaders.setContentType(mediaType);

        return new ResponseEntity("[]", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need some more information to be sure like what encoding type is used for the parameters, but it's like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-AUTH-TOKEN: token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 88fd44ab-692a-bef0-c80e-fe8b98c33bd1" -d '[arg1][arg2][arg3][arg4]' 'http://my.ip.address:port/myProgram'
```

Comment: @SUNDONG I'm missing info on where the input is used, I don't believe it's in the code you provided. And I need to know if the POST is `x-www-form-urlencoded`